# how to list permissions of an rpm which is already installed?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, rpm-maven-plugin

how do i list file permissions of rpm which is already installed?

I know I can do it for rpm file which is not installed using -pqlv. But how do I do for rpm which is already installed when I do not have access to the rpm file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of -p use -q and you are done:

```
rpm -qflv /usr/bin/bash |grep /usr/bin/bash
```